# function SIGN(double x,double y) in c++

Tags: c#, c++, sign

What does function SIGN(double x,double y) do in C++ language and how to translate it to c#

Comment: its not a sign(double) whic returns sign of number this one takes two arguments and I can't find it nowhere on the net

Comment: Maybe because it itsn't a standard C++ function.

Comment: Which C++ library are you using?

Comment: @thb It's lacking important information. Since it's not a standard function, the question can so far only be answered "Whatever the coder made it do, and for translating it, first find out what it does". Or with wild guesses.

Answer (score 2):

A function like that exists in Fortan http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SIGN.html

```
SIGN(A,B) returns the value of A with the sign of B.

If B >= 0 then the result is ABS(A), else it is -ABS(A).
```

Possibly someone implemented the same function in C++ (but something custom, not a standard part of C++ or the standard libraries).

A c# version of that would be

```
  A = Math.Abs(A);
  if (B<0.0) A = -A;
```

Comment: If `A = B = -1` then `A * Math.Sign(B)` will not have the same sign as `B`.

Comment: thanks, in a hurry, will edit.

Comment: `Math.Abs(A) * Math.Sign(B)` should do.

Comment: thank you that is what was the problem

Comment: Math.Sign won't work because it returns 0 if B == 0.

Comment: It's a good idea to either clearly document the preconditions or otherwise throw an exception if `B >= 0` and `A = MIN_VAL` though. Just looked it up: `Math.Abs` in C# does already throw an exception (good thing, java got that wrong), so the code is wrong for one corner case but handles the other fine.

Comment: @Voo - I can see that with integral types, but I don't think that would be an issue for double type inputs since Double.MaxValue = Abs(Double.MinValue).

Comment: @hatchet Ah I see - I thought we were talking about ints here (didn't notice the `< 0.0` check). Yep works fine for doubles.

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ code you are translating to C#, look for a macro definition or inline function definition for `SIGN`. The definition should spell out exactly how you should implement it in C#.

If I had to guess from the name, `SIGN(x,y)` returns true if `x` and `y` have the same sign, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard library has no `SIGN()` function.  Your question does not give enough information for me to tell you for certain what this `SIGN()` is, but C++ succeeds the older programming language C, and my informed hunch is that `SIGN()` is a *preprocessor macro* defined in the old C style.

Search your code for a line that begins `#define SIGN`, possibly with more than one space between the `#define` and the `SIGN`.  If you find the line, it is likely to tell you what your `SIGN()` is and does.